# Time complexity of `std::partition()`

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, time-complexity, quicksort

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition):

> **Complexity**
>   Exactly `std::distance(first,last)` applications of the predicate and at most `std::distance(first,last)` swaps. If
>   ForwardIt meets the requirements of BidirectionalIterator at most
>   `std::distance(first,last)/2` swaps are done.

I looked at the sample implementation at the bottom:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class UnaryPredicate>
ForwardIt partition(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryPredicate p)
{
    if (first == last) return first;
    ForwardIt part(first++);
    if (first == last) return p(*part) ? first : part;
    while (first != last) {
        if (p(*part))
            ++part;
        else if (p(*first)) {
            iter_swap(part, first);
            ++part;
        }
        ++first;
    }
    return part;
}
```

I think it performs at most `std::distance(first,last)/2` swaps instead of `std::distance(first,last)`. No?

Comment: For an example of Alf's answer, `[0,1,1,1,1,1,…]` with the predicate `_ != 0`.

Comment: Note that this implementation is wrong in that it calls the predicate too many times.

Comment: @T.C. ehhh, that's not so. It calls exactly N times

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov Nope, each iteration of the loop can call the predicate twice.

Comment: @T.C. oh, you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be an implemention for non-bidirectional iterator, going forward only. Going forward only through a sequence of *n* items, at least *n*-1 swaps are needed to move a single non-p item from start to end. With bidirectional iterators one can work inwards from both ends.

Comment: The **libstdc++** implementation for bidirectional iterators can be found, e.g., in [stl_algo.h, line 1487](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01499_source.html#l01487) (just below the one for forward iterators).